# On a Persistent LiveUSB installation, user ubuntu cannot access /usr/bin/node

Tags: permissions, live-usb, symbolic-link, nodejs

I have installed Node.js on my Persistent LiveUSB installation of Ubuntu 
16.04.3. I have created a symlink for it at `/usr/bin/node`

As root, I can see that the symlink is healthy. I even make the node file open to all users:

```
$ ls -al /usr/bin/node 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Nov 16 20:48 /usr/bin/node -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.1/bin/node
$ /usr/bin/node -v
v8.8.1
$ chmod 777 /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.1/bin/node
$ ls -al /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.1/bin/node
-rwxrwxrwx 1 500 500 35100284 Oct 25 22:51
```

However, the standard `ubuntu` user seems to have limited access to `/usr/bin`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ /usr/bin/node -v
bash: /usr/bin/node: Permission denied
```

When I use `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -al /usr/bin/node`, the link is shown in red as if it were broken.

Is this a limitation of Persistent LiveUSB installations? Or is there a change I can make that will give my ubuntu user access to this installation of node?

Comment: Not sure / don't know about limitations but a persistent LiveUSB is not "designed" for such use.

Comment: Did you supply the full path, when you created the link? I think a symbolic link works in the same way in a persistent live system as in an installed system.

Answer (score 1):

Giving the access rights for the file node is not enough.
The user ubuntu must have the 'x' permission for all directories leading to node i.e. 

    `/root
    /root/.nvm
    /root/.nvm/versions
    /root/.nvm/versions/node
    /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.1
    /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.1/bin`